# Can you explain inheritance in Nhibernate to me?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, hibernate

Im having a hard time understanding how inheritance works with NHibernate, with regards to mapping with .hbm.xml files.

Comment: Would recommend spending about an hour watching this - http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=51

Answer (score 0):

I've found that series to be very helpful http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/.
Inheritance in NH is not a short story to be explained easily as you've got a few ways to do that.
You can map a class hierarchy to a single table (but some null fields are there), you can map concrete class to a separate tables, but some union query might appears, you can have one table for parent class and separate tables for concrete ones, but some joins are necessary and so on.. (Some other options are there as well).